# Why am I unable to use “ubuntu+1” as a tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'd like to tag [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5257/is-there-a-rational-reason-to-wait-for-the-release-date-to-download-install-or-u) with “ubuntu+1”, which has traditionally been our way of describing the current development focus which will become the next release.  Although the interface suggests that these are all valid characters for a tag, when trying to enter the tag ”ubuntu+1” it ends up as just being “1”.

Comment: This brings up an interesting question - how to deal with current Ubuntu focus version.

Comment: I tagged it dev-release as a work around. Maybe ubuntu-plus-one?

Comment: Ok.  This is therefore a feature request; tagged as such.

Comment: I would put that release's codename since at some point exactly what is +1 will change. And by "some point" I mean "every 6 months"

Comment: Some questions legitimately apply to the current development release, whatever that release happens to be.  For questions which target a particular development release, sure - use the codename.

Answer (score 8):

Tags with a plus in the middle are not allowed; see [Jeff's answer on this Meta.SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45353/how-can-i-create-a-tag-that-contains/52780#52780).